# Append a text to first column only using arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query formula result range with n rows and 2 columns.

[image]

I need to make it display as shown below

[image]

Its prefixing text "MWST (" and suffixing "%)" to the first column

I have tried with

```
=arrayformula("MWST (" & query(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,"Select SUM(M), N where Q = "& $B$10 & "GROUP BY L, N LABEL SUM(M) ''",-1))
```

but this gets prefix for second column too. I am getting this incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Please provide source data - see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your post says you need to "display" the first column as shown. Does this mean you still want the underlying numbers to be available to further formulas for calculation? Or can the final result of the first column be a string (i.e, you don't need the final result to be treated as real numbers)? In addition to answering this, yes—share a link to to a copy of your sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permissions (when you create it) to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your query in 2 parts

```
=ArrayFormula({"MWST ("&
          QUERY(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,
                    "Select SUM(M) where Q = "& $B$10 & "GROUP BY L, N LABEL SUM(M) ''",-1)&")", 
          QUERY(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,
                          "Select N where Q = "& $B$10 & "GROUP BY L, N LABEL SUM(M) ''",-1)})
```

Comment: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG
The second query requires Aggregate function

Comment: @SomethingGood Of course you are right. I didn't try the formula. Please share a test sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Format : `"MWST ("00%")"`