# Prepend text to the first column only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a result range of a query formula with rows and columns [image]

I need to append text "MQ" to first column only

[image]

How do I make it possible? I tried `=Arrayformula("MQ " & QUERYFORMULA )`

Comment: Is this a different question than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518945/append-a-text-to-first-column-only-using-arrayformula-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Please share something more than just a couple of minute images

Comment: Do you still want the underlying numbers to be available to further formulas for calculation? Or can the final result of the first column be a string (i.e, you don't need the final result to be treated as real numbers)? In addition to answering this, please share a link to to a copy of your sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permissions (when you create it) to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula({"MQ",""}&query(A1:B2))
```